# Why my code failed some sample cases on HackerRank although it is okay when i test on my computer?

Tags: python

I am a student now. I started learning Python in my university, however, I learned a little bit C in the past so I tends to analyze problem in C language way.

Yesterday, I did the If-Else practice for Python on HackerRank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-if-else/problem

And this is my first solution:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:" ))
if n % 2 != 0:
print("Weird")
else:
if n>=2 and n<=5 :
    print("Not weird")
if n>=6 and n<=20  :
    print(" Weird")
if n>20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

It worked completely great when I test but when I submit my code on HackerRank, it failed some sample cases, and I found this solution on the Internet:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
if n % 2 == 1:
print("Weird")
elif n % 2 == 0 and 2 <= n <= 5:
print("Not Weird")
elif n % 2 == 0 and 6 <= n <= 20:
print("Weird")
else:
print("Not Weird")
```

SO Is there any difference between 2 solutions and why Solution 2 is preferred on HackerRank?

Comment: First off, there is an issue in your code. `if n>=2 and n=6 and n20`. `n=6` assigns 6 to n. To compare use `n==6`. Also the operator in `n20` is missing.

Comment: Sorry CodingClown, Please check my code again, I just edited it

Comment: Ok. Was it perhaps a testcase where n is between 6 and 20? Because you are printing a space before Weird there. That might make it fail.

Comment: It works, thank you very much my buddy. I always got some problems with details so I gonna try to be more careful with my code. Thanks again!!

Comment: You are very welcome. Yeah. Computers know no mercy :D

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the whitespace at 6 to 20 case. It has to match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code. This code passed all 6 Test cases.

```
    n = int(input().strip())
    if n%2==1:
        print('Weird')
    elif n in range(2, 5+1):
        print('Not Weird')
    elif n in range(6, 20+1):
        print('Weird')
    else:
        print('Not Weird')
```

**NB:** In `range(start, stop)` function the `stop` is not included, so I added `+1` with the last value.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about this answer. I spend a lot of time getting the right
answer I think a probably spend 3 and 4 days on this problem then after so
much effort I found this solution.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input().strip())

if(n%2==1): # i think you can also right 
  print("Weird")

elif(2<n<5):
  print("Not Weird")

elif(6<n<=20):
  print("Weird")

else:
  print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Because the second solution uses `else` and `elif` statements. If you are not using if else there is a chance that multiple if statements are ran at the same time (Although it won't happen in this example but its generally safer and a better practice.). So if you do not want more than one answer, use `elif`. Also the second question is more compact and easier to read. Other than not using `elif` statements there is no difference between the two questions functionality wise.

At the begining you are checking `n % 2 != 0` which indicates an even number while the question at hacker rank asks for an odd number. The second solution fixes this by changing this to `if n % 2 == 1`.

P.S. Check your indentation carefully when posting/coding in python.